# singleton, static or interface as constants fields?

Tags: java, memory-management

I need `final` fields as my app config `constants`.

I know 3 different ways but I don't know which one is the best and and what is JVM behavior in this cases (in the perspective of memory managment and memory issues)

**1. using static fields**

```
public class Constants {
    public static final String URL = "https://www.google.com";
}
//usage
Constants.URL
```

**2. using Interfaces**

```
public interface Constants {
    String URL = "https://www.google.com";
}
//usage
Constants.URL
```

**3. using singleton design pattern ( non-static )**

```
public class Constants {
    public final String URL = "https://www.google.com";
}
//usage
public static Constants instance = new Constants();
Constants.instance.URL;
```

Comment: The recommended way to do this is to include the constants that apply to a class / interface directly in that class / interface definition. Interfaces/Classes like `Calendar` and `GridBagConstraints` provide examples of this

Comment: The difference in memory consumption is negligible, you'll want to decide by other criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of them, use and enum type. Keep in mind the second option is really undesirable, because *the most important point* of interfaces is that you are *defining a new type*.

By the way, enums are singletons (and you can use them like that) and indeed thread-safe by default.

For example:

```
public enum ApplicationStatus {
    LIVE("live"),
    MOCKS("mocks");

    private final String status;

    ApplicationStatus(final String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String value() { return status; }
}
```

And that should apply to really really global messages/constants/etc for the whole application.

Comment: Why would an enum be better? And why does "defining a new type" only apply to interfaces? class and enum declarations also introduce new types ...

Comment: Also added advantage of enums is you can add some behavior to it by defining methods. Which is extremely flexible and powerful.

Comment: @meriton Classes and enums eventually introduce new types, but I explicitly said: _the most important point_

Comment: @ɐuıɥɔɐɯ thank you , could you write about how JVM allocate memory to signalton, interface and enum fields ? , for example in singleton design pattern , when we have an static instance of class, does JVM behavior with fields is same as static fields , ( method 1 and 3 in my question ) ?